# Cell valule read only works first time through loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm relatively new to VBA.  I'm trying to loop through a table and pull a different value each time through the loop.

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim i As Integer
    Windows("CC_1000H.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("CC_1000H").Select

    Dim Count_Accounts As Integer
    Dim NewLine As Integer

    Count_Accounts = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, "H").Value
    i = 0
    Do Until i = Count_Accounts
        i = i + 1
        NewLine = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, "F").Value
        'Rows("4:4").Select Rows(NewLine).Select
        '(More code)
    Loop
End Sub
```

The first time through this loop, the code works fine.  The second time through, the value of Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, "F").Value is empty and NewLine is 0.  It doesn't seem to matter how I reference the cell value, what I is or even if I use I at all.  It won't read a cell the second time.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: what is `i` initial value before entering the `Do Until` loop ? do you have values in all rows of Column F (`F2` , `F3`, `F4`, etc.)   ?  since you are advancing the row count by 1 each time you enter the loop

Comment: This can't be replicated with the code provided. Can you post the entire procedure?

Comment: Indeed. Also what is Count_Accounts? We need to see original assignment.

Comment: Sorry - I don't know why this format looks so awful here.Sub Macro3()

    Dim i As Integer
    Windows("CC_1000H.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("CC_1000H").Select
    
    Dim Count_Accounts As Integer
    Dim NewLine As Integer
    Count_Accounts = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, "H").Value
    
    i = 0
    Do Until i = Count_Accounts
        i = i + 1
    
        NewLine = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, "F").Value
    
        'Rows("4:4").Select
        Rows(NewLine).Select

(More code)

    Loop
    
End Sub

Comment: I do have values in F2, F3, & F4.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of your `Sheet1`?

Comment: ^^^That.  This still isn't enough code to replicate.  Is `i` used *anywhere* else in the `'(More code)` part?

Comment: If you don't have sufficient privilege to upload a picture, upload it to imgur.com and include the link.

Comment: Why are you selecting `"CC_1000H"` and referencing `"Sheet1"`?  Could you be looking at the wrong sheet?

Comment: Sorry - My corporate laptop won't let me do a screenshot (really big pain).  F1 = "Location".  F2 = 4.  F3 = 5.  F4 = 88.  F5 = 91.

Comment: Just tried removing the "CC_1000H" selection and it still had the same problem.  I is not used anywhere else in the (more code) portion.  Because of character limits, I can't post the whole thing.

Comment: Put a stop at the `NewLine` line and look at the value of i and see if it is what you think it should be.

Comment: Already tried putting a breakpoint just above.  I has the correct value.  Newline is 0 and "Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i + 1).Value" is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you looking for this

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim i As Long
    Windows("CC_1000H.xlsx").Activate
    Sheets("CC_1000H").Select
    Dim Count_Accounts As Long
    Dim NewLine As Long
    Count_Accounts = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    i = 0
    Do Until i = Count_Accounts
        i = i + 1
        NewLine = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i + 1).Value
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Same problem.  It works the first time through the loop but the second time "Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & i + 1).Value" is empty and Newline is 0.